# How to extract multi-line text delimited by 2 strings

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I've following pattern:

> Claims(40)
>   This is good.
>   This is good, too.
>   Description
>   This is description.

The delimiter strings in this case are:

> 1st delimiter: "Claims(40)"
>   2nd delimiter: "Description"

I want to extract text between these delimiters while excluding the delimiters.

Also, in the above text, following rules exist:

1. 1st delimiter starts on the 1st column in the text and it's the only word on the line.
2. In the first delimiter, opening parenthesis, combination of digits, and closing parenthesis may be absent. However, combination of digits and closing parenthesis exist if does the opening parenthesis.
3. 2nd delimiter starts on the 1st column in the text and it's the only word on the line.

My regular expression:

`String regxStr = "^Claims(\\(\\d+\\)?)$(.*?)^Description$";`

This doesn't work.

I tried a lot many other regx, but none did work. So finally, I resorted applying brute-force approach with the regex:

`String regxStr = "Claims(.*?)Description";`

But neither of the regx is working. I am not being able to figure out what's and where the regx is going wrong.
I'm using Matcher class and find() method of Matcher class for further processing.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This captures the text you want, although I'm not totally clear on your requirements for the `(40)` part. @lovetostrike's answer addresses that.

```
\bClaims(?:\(\d+\))?\s+(.+?)\s+Description\b
```

You must activate the [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag when compiling the pattern:

```
Pattern.compile(regxStr, Pattern.DOTALL)
```

Escaped in a Java string:

```
"\\bClaims(?:\\(\\d+\\))?\\s+(.+?)\\s+Description\\b"
```

Comment: To be more accurate, shouldn't it be in escaped Java string?
`"Claims\\(\\d+\\)\\s+(.*)\\s+Description"`

Comment: Great, I used "\\bClaims\\(\\d+\\)\\s+(.+?)\\s+Description\\b". Just a slight correction, added '\' after Claims\ in aliterralmind's solution. But can you please help me understand what was wrong in my regex?

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider choosing this as your answer, by clicking on the big check-mark. Best of luck to you, and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `\bClaims\(?:\(\d+\))? ...` is wrong. The parens around the number are indeed escaped: `\(\d+\)`. Perhaps you're talking about a version of my answer that was incorrect, but has since been edited? Refresh the page and take another look. To answer your question, I think the missing `DOTALL` was your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also in addition to @aliteralmind answer, Regex isn't a good tool for nested structure, i.e. matching paren pairs. But in your simple case, you can use the OR, '|', operator in your pattern. The outer parens are used to separate the two groups for OR operator, first part with parens, and the second without parens.

```
(\\(\\d+\\)|\\d+)
```

Comment: Well, the solution is failing if I remove parenthesised text from Claims. Such as "Claims" instead of "Claims(40)". This is happening in both the solutions.

Comment: Can you clarify it? Pls post the exact regex you used and the example string. I tested their solutions and they worked for both "Claims" and "Claims(40)"

Comment: I used the same you gave: \\bClaims(\\(\\d+\\)|\\d+)\\s+(.?)\\s+")Description\\b

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your rule... :D Their solutions are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line solution:

```
String target = input.relaceAll(".*Claims(\\(\\d+\\))?\\s+(.*?)Description.*", "$1");
```